# Showing Updated date instead of Published on my posts

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm trying to change "published at" to "updated at" on my posts.

For example, this is a website with the same Wordpress theme http://charlessledge.com/why-every-man-should-try-muay-thai-at-least-once-darren-mitchell/

Is showing "Posted on March 17, 2019 by Charles Sledge."

But I want to be "Updated on" and then for it to show modified date. Is this complicated?

The goal is to show in Google search result the updated and not posted time. Is this possible with my theme? Thank you.

I searched in code and the only thing I found is this in content.php and content-single.php:

```
  <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php athemes_posted_on(); ?>
            <!-- .entry-meta --></div>
```

Comment: The keywords are (should be) post_date and post_modified.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need `<?php the_modified_date( $d, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>` Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I found is this:

Code:
function athemes_posted_on() {

```
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,

    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),

    esc_html( get_the_date() ),

    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),

    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )

);



printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">Posted on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> by %2$s</span>', 'athemes' ),
```

So I tried to move esc_attr and esc_html of modified date to be first and esc_attr and esc_html of the date second and it showed error. But after that, I just deleted the esc_attr(get_the_date... and esc_html( get_the_date.. and left just for a modified date and viola.

It worked.

So I also changed the printf function and now it says "Updated at" followed by modified time. Great!

The only thing I am worried about is that now, even new posts that aren't being modified show "Updated at" following by published date. Hope this won't be a problem for SEO. Maybe if you know that simply adding the

Updated on:

Will be better for Google crawler, then I would do it that way. But I guess I'm fine.

Anyways, thank you a lot!

Comment: No, no, no.  Do not ever modify theme core files.  If your theme is ever updated, your changes will be lost.  There are other ways to accomplish this, without modifying core theme files.  (Namely, write a small plugin, or make a child theme).  Also, please note that this theme's code is NOT good, if that is the full code from the `athemes_posted_on` function.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Dont worry, im using a child theme. I forgat to tell.